# What kind of language is CSS?

Tags: css, definition

What kind of language is CSS?

My first inclination was to call it a markup language... but it doesn't really fit the mold:

> A markup language is a system for
>   annotating a text in a way which is
>   syntactically distinguishable from
>   that text. -[wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markup_language)

CSS uses various selectors to apply properties to elements *within* HTML, a markup language

Comment: I think that as CSS evolves it will become easier to describe. Interesting recent additions such as the ability to declare animation of elements on certain events.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I would say it is a domain-specific [declarative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Declarative_programming) language.

Comment: This might be true, but it's hardly a useful definition; as most applications of XML, are, in essence, DSDLs, as are a lot of other things.

Comment: DSDL definitions become useful when you know what the domain is. :)

Comment: @Vivian Paliath: Yes; but the definition *of* something as a DSDL is not particularly so.

Comment: It is a broad category but I am not sure you can get any more specific other than saying it is a stylesheet language which is a bit like saying HTML is a hyper text markup language

Comment: These days, I would say CSS is *imperative*, when compared to using pre-made classes in html (eg `.red-heading`). Using a visually descriptive class containing a group of styles is *declarative* in that it describes what to do, but not how to do it. Hand-writing CSS rule-sets is imperative with regards to modern web-development practices.

Comment: I agree with this post. For those interested, read Lloyd's (1994) paper about declarative programming (page 10 at http://www.programmazionelogica.it/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/GP1994-I-000-031.pdf). Declarative focuses on what (e.g., presentation of data) while imperative specify how (e.g., generate / modify data).

Answer (score 6):

Syntactically, CSS is a mix of two languages: the language of selectors, which is a pattern-matching one, like regexps or xpath, and the language of properties, which can be classified as "procedural-declarative", because properties are essentially assignment operators. At a subjective level, css clearly qualifies as ugly mess, like pretty much every other fruit of collective efforts on the field of language design ("a camel is a horse designed by committee").

Comment: ...and C++ is an octopus made by nailing extra legs onto a dog.

Comment: @Michael: That is actually a pretty accurate description of C++

Comment: I'm not sure I'd call any part of CSS "procedural" unless you're talking about expressions, but I'm glad somebody agrees that CSS is an ugly mess. When, in a *formatting* language, the best way to center something is to give it a `margin:auto;` property (and an explicit width), you know something went wrong.

Answer (score 4):

CSS is not *really* a language, per se; it is more of a syntax for describing configuration directives.

In fact, it is neither of these things; CSS is a description of a number of tokens and their visual meanings; .css files contain these tokens structured in manner allowing a computer to parse them. CSS declarations can take the form of name="value" declarations in SVG documents; and the .css file structure could just as easily be employed to, say, contain unit descriptions in a particularly absurd iteration of FreeCiv.

Wikipedias definition of it as a Style sheet language seems like a bit of a forced definition of a generalization of a singularly existing phenomenon; and it should be clear that it is not in any way a markup language, as it doesn't actually, by itself, mark anything up.

Comment: I completely agree that Wikipedia's definition is a bit forced.

Comment: According to W3C, CSS is definitely a language and there are define at least three that fall into this category of languages: css, xpath, xslt - http://www.w3.org/Style/

Comment: Why isn't CSS a language? Clearly, it is not a programming language, but it has its own grammar, so it /is/ formal language.

Comment: @el.pescado: Well, obviously. But I would think that qualifying the word language with a "programming" just seems so unnecessary on SO.

Comment: Writing web pages with HTML and CSS is not programming, so strictly speaking it is off-topic here, though it seems to be tolerated.

Comment: CSS is certainly a programming language. It is true that CSS is not "Turing complete", but it does not need to be in order to be a language. CSS is a declarative programming language that (among other things) manipulates nodes of the DOM in appearance, position, etc., and whose details of implementation (the "How" does it achieve that) are hidden (abstracted) from the user.

Answer (score 3):

**CSS is most definitely a language:**

Wikipedia refers to css as a '*style sheet language*'

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Style_sheet_language

Also from W3C who developed CSS: (comparing [xsl](/questions/tagged/xsl) and [css](/questions/tagged/css))

> The unique features are that CSS can be used to style HTML & XML documents. XSL, on the other hand, is able to transform documents. For example, XSL can be used to transform XML data into HTML/CSS documents on the Web server. This way, the two languages complement each other and can be used together.
>
> **Both languages** can be used to style XML documents.

As you can see from the second sentence W3C refers to CSS as a language.

http://www.w3.org/Style/

And the next quote again from the same article:

> The fact that W3C has developed **XSL** in addition to **CSS** has caused some confusion. Why develop a second **style sheet language** when implementers haven't even finished the first one? The answer can be found in the table below:

```
                            CSS     XSL
Can be used with HTML?      yes      no 
Can be used with XML?       yes     yes
Transformation language?     no     yes
Syntax                      CSS     XML
```

Comment: Yes, I saw that. The article only really gives one example of what "stylesheet" language is... and that's CSS.

Comment: Yes, I also thought that was weird. But then it may be the only one of it's kind so far.

Answer (score 2):

CSS has a well-defined grammar, thus it is a language, and if you had to choose between CSS being declarative or imperative, then it would be declarative, as the results of its operation are determined by the program actually interpreting and processing the CSS.

However, you can't build anything useful with CSS alone; it needs a document to operate on, and all the CSS does is provide supplemental information for the document; effectively, then, the CCS is a part of the document it operates on.

The problem with CSS is that is it used as part of the HTML to DOM generation process; therefore CSS behaves similar to "messy" global variables, and as a result, developers have to deal with the plethora of nasty side effects CSS brings along with it.

Hopefully, Håkon Wium Lie, the inventor of CSS, and a major player at the W3C will one day come to realize that CSS was and is a mistake from the beginning until today and the wrong path to take to achieve a separation of semantic markup and presentation.

Today, CCS is gaining imperative features with @media queries, and targeting with @operators, such as @screen and @print. But none of the new features will correct the fundamentals flaws of CSS: the god-awful globals, and the notorious unreasonable use of side-effects with its element selectors.

Unfortunately, the study of CSS as a language is more complex than the study of real programming languages, as examples of how to use it are more anecdotal than practical, hence the need for comprehensive CSS frameworks like Bootstrap and others to get your job done.